# Error when I reload my Next.js app using animejs: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' This error happened while generating the page

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, es6-modules, animejs

Error when I reload my Next.js app using animejs:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'  This error happened while generating the page.
>
> file:///Users/.../node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.es.js (1310)

This is how I am importing anime.js:

```
import anime from "animejs/lib/anime.es.js";

...
const GLOBAL_CFG = {
    loop: true,
  };

  const GEAR1 = anime({
    loop: true,
    targets: "#gear1 path",
    rotate: 360,
    easing: "linear",
  });

  const GEAR2 = anime({
    ...GLOBAL_CFG,
    targets: "#gear2 path",
    rotate: -360,
    easing: "linear",
  });
```

I am using TypeScript. Here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "globals.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Here's my .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}
```

Next version:

```
"next": "13.2.4",
```

Anime.js

```
 "animejs": "^3.2.1",
 "@types/animejs": "^3.1.7",
```

The code works fine when I write and save it. This error occurs when I reload the page. I am a bit new to Next.js and TypeScript. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by the following:

Replace `import anime from "animejs/lib/anime.es.js"` with  `import anime from "animejs"`,

and the anime code has to be put into useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    anime({
      loop: true,
      targets: "#gear1 path",
      rotate: 360,
      easing: "linear",
    });
  }, []);
```